# Overwriting an entity by reusing its id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If we add a second entity of same Model(NDB) with the same id, would the first entity get replaced by the second entity?
Is this the right way? In future, would this cause any problem?

I use GAE Python with NDB.

Eg,

```
class X (ndb.Model): 
    command = ndb.StringProperty () 

x_record = X (id="id_value", command="c1") 
x_record.put () 


# After some time  
x_record = X (id="id_value", command="c2") 
x_record.put ()
```

I did find a mention of this in official Google docs.

**CONTEXT**
I intend to use it to reduce code steps. Presently, first the code checks if an entity with key X already exists. If it exists, it updates its properties. Else, it creates a new one with that key(X). New approach would be to just blindly create a new entity with key X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would simply replace the model.

Would it cause any problems? Only if you wanted the original model back...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I intend to use it to reduce code steps. Presently, first the code checks if an entity with key X already exists. If it exists, it updates its properties. Else, it creates a new one with that key(X). New approach would be to just blindly create a new entity with key X. I hope you got my context right.

Comment: get_or_insert might be of interest then: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert

Comment: Does it work with NDB too? (since it is present in the db section of the Google official docs)

Comment: yes, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert

Comment: Thanks.. I should have checked that section under NDB before asking :(

Comment: NP. I should have put the correct link in in the first place :)